# Twitter Streaming API track shortened URLs

Tags: twitter, resolve, short-url, twitter-streaming-api

I want to count the twitter mentions of a url with different paths.

Therefore I am using the twitter streaming api with the `track` filter like:

```
track=http://mydomain/abc123,http://mydomain/foo42,http://mydomain/bar21,...
```

This works well, but because the domainname is long, the urls are sometimes automatically shortened. And tweets with those shortened URLs won't appear in my stream.

Is there a method to filter after **resolved** short URLs?

Thanks in advance,
McFarlane